# React native app crash in production, couldn't find "libhermes.so"

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native version 0.72.6, the app works fine for most users, but Firebase crashlytics report that the app crash when users open the app for the first time.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhermes.so"
```

I have searched for solutions for 3 days and can't reproduce error in my emulators. Some of my solutions I've tried:

Solution 1:
Add:

```
packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
    }
```

Not working.

Solution 2:
Add
`android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

Also not working.

I realized that the architecture of user's device so strange: /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm
"arm" does'nt exist in my react native configuration:

gradle.properties:

```
reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64
```

The app only crash on about 10% devices. Thanks in advance

I want the app works on many devices as I can

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36539#issuecomment-1539870803 refer to this

Comment: @VinXi: my app/build.gradle does'nt have that line, last line of my app/build.gradle: apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)